How to get Swedish coins in Sweden?
I can get cash as banknotes from Bankomat, but how can I get Swedish coins, regular and commemorative that are legal tender? I contacted my bank (Nordea), but they are cashless. For example I want a specific amount of coins of specific denomination, say 50 ten krona coins.

You can buy them at Forex for a fee: https://www.forex.se/en/customer-service/checkout-services/
